# Getting data from Wikipedia API with Query Action without LaTex

Tags: javascript, json, latex, wikipedia-api, mathml

I am working of a website that extracts data from various APIs, including the biggest source Wikipedia API.
I am using Query Action and Extract Prop to get all the data but my page is little bit Science Oriented so people very often ask about things like Quadratic  Equation, Plank Constant and other relative terms.
Now, the problem is that when I get information of these types of topics the answer comes but the answers are highly FORMULA based and the Wikipedia sends that data in form of LaTex (encoding="application/x-tex") and MathML and the browser reads it weirdly and just shows it in simple text form and the whole data almost becomes useless.
So can someone tell me how to do that??

Example : https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=jsonfm&action=query&prop=extracts&callback=getMoreData&titles=Planck%20constant

And in the example above the formulas are written like :

```
<math xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML\">\n  <semantics>\n    <mrow class=\"MJX-TeXAtom-ORD\">\n      <mstyle displaystyle=\"true\" scriptlevel=\"0\">\n        <mi>E</mi>\n        <mo>=</mo>\n        <mi>h</mi>\n        <mi>f</mi>\n      </mstyle>\n    </mrow>\n    <annotation encoding=\"application/x-tex\">{\\displaystyle E=hf}</annotation>\n  </semantics></math>
```

The browser doesn't interprets it and shows something like this :
[Snapshot from my page after searching for Planck Constant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aW8Xa.png)

Comment: you can use any library which converts that Latex to readable output. e.g. http://www.intmath.com/blog/mathematics/katex-a-new-way-to-display-math-on-the-web-9445

Comment: You will need a MathML renderer like MathJax.

Comment: Created a bug for that: https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T159065

Comment: @MaxSem Is it really a bug? By the way any solutions around?

Comment: It says "decide what to do" ;)